# How to force new line without html tags

Tags: html, css

I there,

Is there a way to force html don't ignore the new lines inserted by a new line key?

For example I have this:

```
<span>Attention to registered measurement values relating to:
Patient: Jose
Parameter(s): Ar</span>
```

Is there any css style or something to apply on the span? I must not use tags like br..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use tags like `<pre>` or `<code>` as appropriate for the content.

```
<pre>Attention to registered measurement values relating to:
Patient: Jose
Parameter(s): Ar</pre>
```

You also use CSS `white-space: pre;`:

```
<span style="white-space: pre;">Attention to registered measurement values relating to:
Patient: Jose
Parameter(s): Ar</span>
```

Comment: But those *ARE* html tags.

Comment: But not within in the container HTML. They just replace the `<span>` tags. And they are not `<br>` tags which is all they specified.