# ajax response ignores line breaks at appending into an element

Tags: jquery, html, laravel

I'm retrieving data from a text type field of my database. I did the backend with Laravel and in the administration part, when i retrieve it into a textarea input with PHP it shows correctly the line breaks.

now i need retrieve it dinamically with ajax and append it into a p element, but when i do it the text is showed as a single line.

i've tried appending with the methods .html() and .append() instead of .text() but i get the same result.

When i print the json response in the console, i can see a symbol of line break where it corresponds.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/getProduct/' + id,
}).done(function(resp) {
    $('#popup-features').text(resp.features);
})
```

This is what console.log returns:

[image]

When i clic in features, it shows the line breaks:

[image]

Comment: HTML in general ignores some whitespace, unless you tell it not to with a `pre` tag, or css styling that applies the same rule.

Comment: .text() won't work , you need to use .html() but I don't know why .html() didn't work for you, can you show what you are getting in resp.excerpt?

Comment: @KarthikGanesan html doesn't care about new lines.  That's why `<br>` exists

Comment: @Taplar I know that and that's the reason I am asking OP to show what he is getting as response

Comment: @KarthikGanesan i just added some screenshots about it

Comment: @KenRamirez did you try css ->  p{
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force new line without html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291907/how-to-force-new-line-without-html-tags)

Comment: @KarthikGanesan yes! it works but adds some extra spaces at begin.

Comment: @Taplar yes it works. I thought that i was doing smth bad because when i retrieved it with XMLHttpRequest() as append with innerText() it shows the line breaks correctly (no css or extra tags needed).

Comment: is you P element specific component? I mean popup , vuejs, reactjs ,...?

Comment: @SamanAhmadi its a single html tag, not generated dinamically